# Crear Estructura HTML Dinámicamente con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, materialize

Estoy intentando crear una estructura, con 3 Json que recibo. La estructura consta de Titulo, Subtitulo y Detalles.

Un Titulo puede tener varios subtitulos y un subtitulo puede tener varios detalles, como la siguiente imágen:

*Estructura*

[image: Estructura]

Para esto los json traen los siguientes datos:

```
Json 1 Titulo:
IdPerspectiva, Perspectiva 

Json 2 Subtitulo:
IdPerspectiva, IdTipoDeIndicador,Nombre

Json 3 Detalles:
Nombre,IdTipoDeIndicador
```

Entonces lo que hago es:

1. Genero todos los Titulos junto con un div con el idPerspectiva
2. Genero los subtítulos y con un `innerHtml` reemplazo la sintaxis del `div` generado en el paso 1, para agregarle el subtitulo, y genero un `div` mas, con el idTipoIndicador
3. Genero los detalles y con un `innerHtml` reemplazo la sintaxis del `div` generado en el paso 2, para agregar los detalles

El problema que tengo es que no se logran relacionar correctamente los subtitulos con el titulo, ni los detalles con el subtitulo.

No se si al utilizar `innerHtml`, se destruye el `div` al que le estoy agregando la nueva sintaxis.

El resultado queda a medias, y en la consola puedo ver el error:

```
FrmMetasDiarioEnergia.aspx:309 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (FrmMetasDiarioEnergia.aspx:309)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (FrmMetasDiarioEnergia.aspx:294)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.min.js:2)
```

*Estructura Error*

[image: Estructura Error]

```js
var encabezado = [{
  "IdPerspectiva": 1,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Financiera"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 2,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Clientes"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 3,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Procesos Internos"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 4,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Aprendizaje y Crecimiento "
}];

var subtitulo = [{
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1,
  "Nombre": "Generar energía eficientemente",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2,
  "Nombre": "Entregar energía a Comercialización, de buena calidad al menor costo",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3,
  "Nombre": "Ejecutar los gastos alineados al presupuesto establecido",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 4,
  "Nombre": "Mantener un alto indicador de disponibilidad y confiabilidad en la generación de energía.",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 5,
  "Nombre": "Despachar según programa de venta de energía",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 6,
  "Nombre": "Proveer calidad de vapor a Fabrica de Azúcar para sus procesos",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7,
  "Nombre": "Realizar una operación segura",
  "IdPerspectiva": 3
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8,
  "Nombre": "Mantener los equipos funcionando bajo las especificaciones técnicas",
  "IdPerspectiva": 3
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9,
  "Nombre": "Implementar una cultura de seguridad personal basada en principios y valores",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10,
  "Nombre": "Registrar gestión de compras",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11,
  "Nombre": "Cumplir con los requerimientos de Recurso humano para la operación",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}];

var detalles = [{
  "IdIndicador": 1,
  "Nombre": "Promedio Generación Bruta de KW por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 2,
  "Nombre": "Promedio Generación Venta de KW por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 3,
  "Nombre": "Ton de Carbón por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 4,
  "Nombre": "Ton de Bagazo por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 5,
  "Nombre": "KWh / Ton Carbón",
  "Calculo": "KWh Carbón / Ton Carbón",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 6,
  "Nombre": "KWh / Ton biomasa",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bagazo / Ton Bagazo",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 7,
  "Nombre": "Kw / Ton de vapor",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta / Ton Vapor",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 8,
  "Nombre": "Kw / Ton de agua DM ",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta / Ton Agua DM",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 9,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de vapor hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 10,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de agua de alimentación a la caldera",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 11,
  "Nombre": "BTU / Lb de carbón (Poder Calorifico)",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 12,
  "Nombre": "BTU / Lb de Biomasa (Poder Calorifico)",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 13,
  "Nombre": "Consumo de energía de auxiliares",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta - Kwh Venta",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 14,
  "Nombre": "Heat rate BTU / Kw",
  "Calculo": "[(Ton Carbón x 2204 x PoderCalorificoCarbón) + (Ton Bagazo x 2204 x PoderCalorificoBagazo)] / KWh Bruta",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 15,
  "Nombre": "Horas en línea por día",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 16,
  "Nombre": "Compra de energía",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 17,
  "Nombre": "Perdida de potencia en la línea",
  "Calculo": "(KWh Venta B4 + KWh Venta B3 - KWh Compra B4 - KWh Compra B3) - (KWh Venta PE - KWh Compra PE)",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 18,
  "Nombre": "Programa de generación Diario",
  "Calculo": "Generado / Programado * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 19,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Mano de Obra",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 20,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Insumos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 21,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Servicios Externos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 22,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Servicios Internos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 23,
  "Nombre": "Horas en línea por día.",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 4
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 24,
  "Nombre": "Programa de generación Diario.",
  "Calculo": "Generado / Programado * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 5
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 25,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de vapor hora.",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 6
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 26,
  "Nombre": "Fatalidades",
  "Calculo": "Numero de fatalidades",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 27,
  "Nombre": "Accidentes registrados",
  "Calculo": "Numero de accidentes",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 28,
  "Nombre": "Colisiones vehiculares",
  "Calculo": "Numero de colisiones",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 29,
  "Nombre": "Suspensiones por lesiones laborales",
  "Calculo": "Suspendidos / Total de empleados * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 30,
  "Nombre": "Llamadas de atención por faltas a la seguridad",
  "Calculo": "Llamadas de atención / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 31,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos mantenimiento preventivo",
  "Calculo": "Preventivos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 32,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos mantenimiento correctivo",
  "Calculo": "Correctivos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 33,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos proyectos de mantenimiento ",
  "Calculo": "Proyectos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 34,
  "Nombre": "Llamadas de atención por faltas a la seguridad.",
  "Calculo": "Llamadas de atención / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 35,
  "Nombre": "Horas Hombre de entrenamiento",
  "Calculo": "Horas de capacitación por colaborador / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 36,
  "Nombre": "Ordenes de servicio realizadas",
  "Calculo": "Total de OS finalizadas",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 37,
  "Nombre": "Ordenes de compra",
  "Calculo": "Total OC Solicitadas",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 38,
  "Nombre": "Compras de emergencia .",
  "Calculo": "Total de compras por emergencia",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 39,
  "Nombre": "Horas extras por trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "Calculo": "Total de horas extras por mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 40,
  "Nombre": "Ausencias de personal",
  "Calculo": "Ausentes / Total de empleados en turno * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 41,
  "Nombre": "Suspensiones por enfermedad",
  "Calculo": "Suspendidos / Total de empleados * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 42,
  "Nombre": "Fuerza Laboral",
  "Calculo": "Cantidad de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}];

$('#btnBuscar').click(function() {
  var html = '';
  $.each(encabezado, function(i, item) {
    html += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">' +
      '<ul class="collection z-depth-2">' +
      '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
      '<i class="material-icons circle red">play_arrow</i>' +
      '<span class="title">' + 'Perspectiva' + '</span>' +
      '<p>' +
      item.IdPerspectiva +
      '<br>' +
      'Second Line' +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<div id="idPerspectiva-' + item.IdPerspectiva + '" data-encabezado="' + item.IdPerspectiva + '"></div>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '</div>';
  });

  document.getElementById('Estructura').innerHTML = html;
  generarSubtitulos();
});

function generarSubtitulos() {
  $.each(subtitulo, function(i, item) {
    var htmli = '<li class="collection-item avatar"><i class="material-icons circle green">insert_chart</i>' +
      '<p>Perspectiva' +
      item.IdPerspectiva +
      '<br> Indicador ' +
      item.IdTipoIndicador +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></a>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<div id="idTipoIndicador-' + item.IdTipoIndicador + '" data-detalles="' + item.IdTipoIndicador + '"></div>';
    var subtitulo = document.getElementById('idPerspectiva-' + item.IdPerspectiva)
    subtitulo.innerHTML = htmli;
  });
  generarDetalles();
}

function generarDetalles() {
  $.each(detalles, function(i, item) {
    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

    setTimeout(function() {
      //your code to be executed after 1 second
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
    var htmli2 = '<li class="collection-item avatar"><i class="material-icons circle yellow">insert_chart</i>' +
      '<p>' +
      item.Nombre +
      '<br>' +
      'Second Line' +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>' +
      '</li>';
    var detalle = document.getElementById('idTipoIndicador-' + item.IdTipoIndicador);
    detalle.innerHTML = htmli2;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="btnBuscar" type="button" value="Buscar" style="width: 100%; margin-top:10px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="Estructura">
  </div>
</div>
```

Intente solucionarlo de varias maneras pero no logro hacer que funcione correctamente. Si pudieran ayudarme muy agradecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estas usando todo el potencial de jQuery.  Estas mezclando jQuery con vanilla javascript.  En lugar de usar `innerHTML`, usa jQuery `append`, de lo contrario, jQuery no reconoce los elementos nuevos.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var encabezado = [{
  "IdPerspectiva": 1,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Financiera"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 2,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Clientes"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 3,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Procesos Internos"
}, {
  "IdPerspectiva": 4,
  "Nombre": "Perspectiva Aprendizaje y Crecimiento "
}];

var subtitulo = [{
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1,
  "Nombre": "Generar energía eficientemente",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2,
  "Nombre": "Entregar energía a Comercialización, de buena calidad al menor costo",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3,
  "Nombre": "Ejecutar los gastos alineados al presupuesto establecido",
  "IdPerspectiva": 1
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 4,
  "Nombre": "Mantener un alto indicador de disponibilidad y confiabilidad en la generación de energía.",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 5,
  "Nombre": "Despachar según programa de venta de energía",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 6,
  "Nombre": "Proveer calidad de vapor a Fabrica de Azúcar para sus procesos",
  "IdPerspectiva": 2
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7,
  "Nombre": "Realizar una operación segura",
  "IdPerspectiva": 3
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8,
  "Nombre": "Mantener los equipos funcionando bajo las especificaciones técnicas",
  "IdPerspectiva": 3
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9,
  "Nombre": "Implementar una cultura de seguridad personal basada en principios y valores",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10,
  "Nombre": "Registrar gestión de compras",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}, {
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11,
  "Nombre": "Cumplir con los requerimientos de Recurso humano para la operación",
  "IdPerspectiva": 4
}];

var detalles = [{
  "IdIndicador": 1,
  "Nombre": "Promedio Generación Bruta de KW por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 2,
  "Nombre": "Promedio Generación Venta de KW por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 3,
  "Nombre": "Ton de Carbón por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 4,
  "Nombre": "Ton de Bagazo por hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 5,
  "Nombre": "KWh / Ton Carbón",
  "Calculo": "KWh Carbón / Ton Carbón",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 6,
  "Nombre": "KWh / Ton biomasa",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bagazo / Ton Bagazo",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 7,
  "Nombre": "Kw / Ton de vapor",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta / Ton Vapor",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 8,
  "Nombre": "Kw / Ton de agua DM ",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta / Ton Agua DM",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 9,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de vapor hora",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 10,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de agua de alimentación a la caldera",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 11,
  "Nombre": "BTU / Lb de carbón (Poder Calorifico)",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 12,
  "Nombre": "BTU / Lb de Biomasa (Poder Calorifico)",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 13,
  "Nombre": "Consumo de energía de auxiliares",
  "Calculo": "KWh Bruta - Kwh Venta",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 14,
  "Nombre": "Heat rate BTU / Kw",
  "Calculo": "[(Ton Carbón x 2204 x PoderCalorificoCarbón) + (Ton Bagazo x 2204 x PoderCalorificoBagazo)] / KWh Bruta",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 1
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 15,
  "Nombre": "Horas en línea por día",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 16,
  "Nombre": "Compra de energía",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 17,
  "Nombre": "Perdida de potencia en la línea",
  "Calculo": "(KWh Venta B4 + KWh Venta B3 - KWh Compra B4 - KWh Compra B3) - (KWh Venta PE - KWh Compra PE)",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 18,
  "Nombre": "Programa de generación Diario",
  "Calculo": "Generado / Programado * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 2
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 19,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Mano de Obra",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 20,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Insumos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 21,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Servicios Externos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 22,
  "Nombre": "Ejecución de presupuesto Servicios Internos",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 3
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 23,
  "Nombre": "Horas en línea por día.",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 4
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 24,
  "Nombre": "Programa de generación Diario.",
  "Calculo": "Generado / Programado * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 5
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 25,
  "Nombre": "Flujo de vapor hora.",
  "Calculo": "",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 6
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 26,
  "Nombre": "Fatalidades",
  "Calculo": "Numero de fatalidades",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 27,
  "Nombre": "Accidentes registrados",
  "Calculo": "Numero de accidentes",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 28,
  "Nombre": "Colisiones vehiculares",
  "Calculo": "Numero de colisiones",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 29,
  "Nombre": "Suspensiones por lesiones laborales",
  "Calculo": "Suspendidos / Total de empleados * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 30,
  "Nombre": "Llamadas de atención por faltas a la seguridad",
  "Calculo": "Llamadas de atención / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 7
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 31,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos mantenimiento preventivo",
  "Calculo": "Preventivos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 32,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos mantenimiento correctivo",
  "Calculo": "Correctivos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 33,
  "Nombre": "Trabajos proyectos de mantenimiento ",
  "Calculo": "Proyectos / Total de trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 8
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 34,
  "Nombre": "Llamadas de atención por faltas a la seguridad.",
  "Calculo": "Llamadas de atención / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 35,
  "Nombre": "Horas Hombre de entrenamiento",
  "Calculo": "Horas de capacitación por colaborador / Total de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 9
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 36,
  "Nombre": "Ordenes de servicio realizadas",
  "Calculo": "Total de OS finalizadas",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 37,
  "Nombre": "Ordenes de compra",
  "Calculo": "Total OC Solicitadas",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 38,
  "Nombre": "Compras de emergencia .",
  "Calculo": "Total de compras por emergencia",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 10
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 39,
  "Nombre": "Horas extras por trabajos de mantenimiento",
  "Calculo": "Total de horas extras por mantenimiento",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 40,
  "Nombre": "Ausencias de personal",
  "Calculo": "Ausentes / Total de empleados en turno * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 41,
  "Nombre": "Suspensiones por enfermedad",
  "Calculo": "Suspendidos / Total de empleados * 100",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}, {
  "IdIndicador": 42,
  "Nombre": "Fuerza Laboral",
  "Calculo": "Cantidad de colaboradores",
  "IdTipoIndicador": 11
}];

$('#btnBuscar').click(function() {
  var html = '';
  $.each(encabezado, function(i, item) {
    html += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">' +
      '<ul class="collection z-depth-2">' +
      '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
      '<i class="material-icons circle red">play_arrow</i>' +
      '<span class="title">' + 'Perspectiva' + '</span>' +
      '<p>' +
      item.IdPerspectiva +
      '<br>' +
      'Second Line' +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<div id="idPerspectiva-' + item.IdPerspectiva + '" data-encabezado="' + item.IdPerspectiva + '"></div>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '</div>';
  });

  $("#Estructura").append(html);
  generarSubtitulos();
});

function generarSubtitulos() {
  $.each(subtitulo, function(i, item) {
    var htmli = '<li class="collection-item avatar"><i class="material-icons circle green">insert_chart</i>' +
      '<p>Perspectiva' +
      item.IdPerspectiva +
      '<br> Indicador ' +
      item.IdTipoIndicador +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></a>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<div id="idTipoIndicador-' + item.IdTipoIndicador + '" data-detalles="' + item.IdTipoIndicador + '"></div>';    
    var subtitulo = $('#idPerspectiva-' + item.IdPerspectiva);
    subtitulo.append(htmli);
  });
  generarDetalles();
}

function generarDetalles() {
  $.each(detalles, function(i, item) {
    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

    setTimeout(function() {
      //your code to be executed after 1 second
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
    var htmli2 = '<li class="collection-item avatar"><i class="material-icons circle yellow">insert_chart</i>' +
      '<p>' +
      item.Nombre +
      '<br>' +
      'Second Line' +
      '</p>' +
      '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>' +
      '</li>';
    var detalle = $('#idTipoIndicador-' + item.IdTipoIndicador);
    detalle.append(htmli2);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="btnBuscar" type="button" value="Buscar" style="width: 100%; margin-top:10px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="Estructura">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @alanfcm. Debo mejorar mi programación, para evitar caer en los errores que me indicas.

Comment: De nada @raintrooper.  Si es una buena practica que no mezcles los dos.  Si vas a usar jQuery, trata de aprender todas sus funciones.